# push local environment variable stored in .env.local to Vercel project

Tags: next.js, vercel

How to push *all* environment variables stored in `.env.local` to a Vercel project?

Do I really need to add them one by one with

`vercel env add [name] [environment] [gitbranch] < [file]`

as specified in the docs
https://vercel.com/docs/cli/env

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Vercel CLI for that, here is link to the CLI docs https://vercel.com/docs/cli

And some examples:

– Pull all Development Environment Variables down from the cloud

```
vercel env pull <file>
vercel env pull .env.development.local
```

– Add a new variable to multiple Environments

```
vercel env add <name>
vercel env add API_TOKEN
```

– Add a new variable for a specific Environment

```
vercel env add <name> <production | preview | development> <gitbranch>
vercel env add DB_PASS preview feat1
```

– Add a new Environment Variable from stdin

```
cat <file> | vercel env add <name> <production | preview | development>
cat ~/.npmrc | vercel env add NPM_RC preview
vercel env add API_URL production < url.txt
```

– Remove a variable from multiple Environments

```
vercel env rm <name>
vercel env rm API_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now copy your `.env` to clipboard, go to your Vercel environment variables in project settings, and just paste in the file to create in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too, but at the time of writing, there's no way to bulk add environment variables using the `vercel` CLI tool. The next best thing would be to use the REST API, as explained [here](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/4977#discussioncomment-3308453). The downside is that it consumes JSON, so you'll need to transform .env.local into a valid JSON payload.

The API requires a bearer token, but it's the same token you pass to the `vercel` commands.

Here's an example :

```
curl -X POST "https://api.vercel.com/v10/projects/your-project-name/env?upsert=true" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $VERCEL_TOKEN" \
  -v \
  -d @vars.json
```

With vars.json being :

```
[
  {
    "key": "TEMP_VAR1",
    "target": ["development"],
    "type": "plain",
    "value": "abcde"
  },
  {
    "key": "TEMP_VAR2",
    "target": ["preview", "development"],
    "type": "plain",
    "value": "lmnopq"
  }
]
```